# Photoelectric Current

Tags: electrons, electric-current, frequency, intensity

Recently learnt that Intensity= nhv ; where n is the number of photos per unit area
My textbook specifies that the photoelectric current only depends upon the number of photons striking per unit time and area. So, why is that photoelectric current remains constant when frequency is changed keeping the Intensity constant?
ie- if intensity is kept constant and frequency is doubled , shouldn't the photoelectric current become half the value? 
Edit: I understand how frequency affects intensity ,just want to know what exactly  controls photoelectric current; intensity or number of electrons.

Comment: Please give more information: In which experimental setting and in which material is this photoelectric current generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you are not able to grasp the concept properly.If we increase the frequency then we are increasing the energy of an individual photon,we are not increasing the number of photons.Imagine it in this way.I guess that we all have seen some cartoons at some stage of our lives where the character throws balls of energy.Now say the character faced a powerful villain then it'll have to send more powerful ball of energy to defeat the villain compared to the normal minions.Now,relate that thing over here.You increased the energy of the photon which means that now the electrons,they will come out with more kinetic energy but still the number of photon colliding with an electron is one and so the speed with which electron comes out change but not the current.

Now let's come to intensity.Now say the hero sent like hundreds of balls of energy in the form of a beam towards villain.But still all of them have the same energy.Now relate that over here.You increased the intensity.This means that number of photons in the beam have increased but still they are of same energy level i.e. hv and we all know that one photon strikes one electron which is responsible for ejection of electron.So more the number of photons,more the number of collision of photon with loosely bonded electrons and more they will come out.Increasing the frequency only increase the energy of photon but still it'll collide with only one electron.So,to increase photoelectric current,we need more electrons as flow of electrons constitute the current and number of electrons coming out will increase only if we increase the number of photons falling on plate.

Hope you found it helpful.

Comment: Thanks, so basically only number of photons control the photoelectric current right? So if intensity if constant and frequency is say increased, so number of photons must decrease for 'nhv' to be constant which would decrease the current right?

Comment: You still didn't got it.By increasing or decreasing the frequency,we are just increasing or decreasing the energy of photons.We are not meddling with intensity.I would suggest you to make a barrier between wave and particle nature of light.Say we consider VIBGYOR.Now say in it we consider red and violet light.We all know that wavelength of violet is less than wavelength of red which means that energy of violet light is more than energy of red light.Now,say we had two types of red light.One which is dim enough so that we see it directly with naked eye and other is the one which we cannot

Comment: So the relation I = nhv doesn't hold true??

Comment: So can I say that the dim light has got less intensity.If it has less intensity then can I say it has less number of photon than the second one.But still red light is red light and so both of their photon has same energy but the difference is arising between number of photons between two different sources of red light due to which we can easily glaze or see the dim one but weren't able to see the brighter one.

Comment: The formula I=nhv hold true but if we are increasing the frequency of photon then say wavelength will also change.If wavelength changes then say you had red light first but now it could be like yellow or violet light starts coming out.I would suggest you to read some standard book to get you concepts cleared.

Comment: Yes yes. I get what you are trying to say . Let me put it this way , suppose you have red light and violet light of the same intensity. Now photons of violet light are more energetic than red light. So for them to have the same intensity number of photons of red light must be more right?